# Why does Russell's Paradox mean that there cannot be a universal set?

Tags: set-theory

I was reading The Foundations of Mathematics by Ian Stewart which discussed the existence of a universal set $\Omega$. It included the following:

*If we select from the putative set $\Omega $
the subset comprising everything that is a set but does not belong to itself,
we get:*

*$S = \{A \in \Omega \mid A \not \in A \}$*

*Now ask the key question: is $S \in S$?*

*- If $S \in S$, then, according to the defining predicate, $S \not \in S$.*

*- If $S \not \in S$, then $S$ satisfies the defining predicate, so $S \in S$.*

*Our flight of fancy in assuming the existence of a universe  has led to a
paradox. Therefore there **cannot be a universal set**.*

How does this paradox imply that universal set $\Omega$ cannot exist?

Comment: Because assuming its existence , we can derive the contradiction , so the existence of such a set makes the set theory inconsistent. The only way out is to forbid such a set (and not only that, in fact set theory became much weaker because of this surprising , not at all expected contradiction)

Comment: The duplicate is perhaps slightly different, but my answer there touches on exactly this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This comes from the [axiom of specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_specification). The existence of the set $\Omega$ allows you to construct $S = \lbrace A \in \Omega \mid A \notin A \rbrace$. Whithout $\Omega$, you cannot define a set using a proprety that's about sets (such as $\notin$ itself). The only assumption you made here is the existence of $\Omega$. Hence, it cannot exist.

Comment: I hope I understood your correctly. Axiom of specification works for any given set and any predicate (including the one describe above for the subset S).  However, if the given set is a universal set, using that predicate leads to a paradox, so there cannot be a universal set. Correct me if I am wrong. Thanks.